# Browse for a File from Excel VBA

Tags: excel, excel-2003, fileopendialog, vba

How can I put up a "File Open" dialog from some VBA running in Excel?

I'm using Excel 2003.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You want the `Application.GetOpenFilename` function. Copying from VBA Object Browser:

> Function GetOpenFilename([FileFilter], [FilterIndex], [Title], [ButtonText], [MultiSelect])
>       Member of Excel.Application

Answer (score 2):

Add a reference to ComDLG32.OCX and then something like...

```
Sub PromptForFile()
Dim d As New MSComDlg.CommonDialog

d.Filter = "xls"
d.Filename = "*.xls"
d.ShowOpen

Excel.Workbooks.Open d.Filename

Set d = Nothing
End Sub
```