# How to Make a VBA Excel Program Work on Other Excel Documents?

Tags: vba, excel, filechooser

I'm very new with VBA Excel and i only know the things as far as i need for this report formatting task. My code is almost completed, but what i wonder is, how can i make my program work on several documents?

I mean, i want to choose an excel file via my program, then i want to start the process of report formatting. Then maybe user need to format another document, i want my program to be able to format that document too. how can i achieve that?

Thanks in Advance

Timur

Comment: Your `this document` will work as the application with a `user form` to control/format other documents.

Comment: So, in order to use this program to manipulate other files, my current file must be saved because i cannot seperate them?

How can i add a file chooser control to my form and use my code to manipulate my target file?

Comment: You are in the right direction. You can even have a report template within your master control file. [check this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/221444/browse-for-a-file-from-excel-vba)

Comment: The documents that need to be formated are always the same files or they can also be newly created files? I ask this because maybe you can include a format macro on those documents and call it from your "main" file.  See this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2806065/running-excel-macro-from-another-workbook)

Comment: Hi @Octavio, Thanks for reply. Actually the documents that need to formatted are our analysis results from CAST AI Platform and we need to format it for IBM RTC. Our client is a bank and my program is suppose to work on a several projects' report formatting task.

I think in my case eventhough data are different, my initial and target tables' column headers are same for every project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I am currently doing this is by creating an Excel add-in.  To do this, place your macros and forms into a new, empty Excel workbook and save as a .xlam document.

To use the macros, open the your Excel file and the add-in.  To open the add-in automatically, save it to "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office12\XLSTART" (Vista).

You can even create a custom ribbon for your add-in using the Custom UI Editor for Microsoft Office http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee691832(v=office.14).aspx (The download link is at the end of the instructions)

Comment: Hi, Thanks for reply. I think this is the solution that i'm looking for. But can you explain whay you mean by ** " To use the macros, open the your Excel file and the add-in " **  ? :)

I'm  little bir confused because i'm new with vba. I understand tha part opening excel file but how can i open the add-in? By add-in do you mean vba editor? :S Shall i press ALT+F11 ? :) :) (a)

Comment: Sorry for the confusion.  When you save a workbook with the .xlam file extension it becomes an Excel add-in.  Add-ins can be open in the same Excel instance as any workbook.  This allows you to access all of the macros in the add-in from whatever workbook you are working on.

For example, imagine you created an add-in called ExAddin.xlam and a workbook Work.xlsx.  You would open Work.xlsx then ExAddin.xlam.  Then the macros in ExAddin.xlam would be accessible in Work.xlsx.

Comment: So, in order to make it working on other excel file, i should run my initial file first? :s (pardon my confusion, i'm not native in english)

Comment: Simply open whatever file you want to work on, then open the Excel add-in (your .xlam file).  Sorry, I don't know how else to explain it.  This will be much more clear after you make your first add-in.